# How to target a specific <img> element of a div in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've a code of some what like this:

```
<div id="foo">
 <img src="bar.png" align="right">
 <img src="cat.png" align="right"> 
</div>
```

Now my question is how do I target a specific image in CSS when having the above code?

Comment: Target how? CSS selectors let you target 'nth-child' type stuff, by tag attributes, etc...

Comment: Are you implying that you cannot change the HTML? Also note that `align` on `<img>` was deprecated in HTML4 and is now obsolete in HTML5.

Comment: Yup, I'm forced to use the above code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add a class to the images OR

```
.foo img:nth-child(2) { css here }
```

or

```
.foo img:first-child { css here }
.foo img:last-child { css here }
```

Answer (score 17):

It depends entirely upon which image you want to target. Assuming it's the first (though the implementations are similar for both) image:

```
#foo img[src="bar.png"] {
    /* css */
}


#foo img[src^="bar.png"] {
    /* css */
}

#foo img:first-child {
    /* css */
}

#foo img:nth-of-type(1) {
    /* css */
}
```

References:

- [CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Answer (score 16):

I don't know why everyone is so fixed on the #foo div. You can target the img tag and not even worry about the div tag. These attribute selectors select by the "begins with".

```
img[src^=bar] { css }
img[src^=cat] { css }
```

These select by "contains".

```
img[src*="bar"] { css }
img[src*="cat"] { css }
```

Or you can select by the exact src.

```
img[src="bar.png"] { css }
img[src="cat.png"] { css }
```

If you want to target them both, then you could use the div id.

```
#foo img { css }
```

For just one of the images, there is no need to worry about the #foo div at all.

Comment: because  OP says "in the div"

Comment: I get that. I wasn't concerned with the div. It's irrelevant. OP wants to target the img not the div.

Answer (score 1):

```
div > img:first-child {/*the first image*/}
div > img:last-child {/*the last image*/}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

All of the following solutions only work in recent browsers.

You can select by child position:

```
 #foo img:first-child { /* for the bar */ }
 #foo img:nth-child(2) { /* for the cat */ }
```

You can select by child position, counting only images:

```
 #foo img:first-of-type { /* for the bar */ }
 #foo img:nth-of-type(2) { /* for the cat */ }
```

You can select by image URL:

```
 #foo img[src^=bar] { /* for the bar */ }
 #foo img[src^=cat] { /* for the cat */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#foo > IMG:first-child {/* first of two IMGs */}
#foo > IMG + IMG       {/* second one */}
```

Works in all browsers including IE7+.