# How to refer to an image with a certain id thats into a section with a certain id - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a site, and i want to use `@media` to make it responsive. 
I'm thinking of using the `content:url("image.jpg")` to get the image with the dimension I want, but I don't know how to put an image with a id that's inside a section with another id into CSS.

My html is like:

```
<section id="1">
    <img class="photo" id="1"/>
    <img class="photo" id="2"/>
    <img class="photo" id="3"/>
</section>
```

Comment: 1. In a page no two ids must be same. So lets say your section id is called `a`. 2. To select first img use the css selector `#a #1`. For second `#a #2`..and so on. 3. For selecting all images, do `#a .photo`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to target a specific <img> element of a div in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036243/how-to-target-a-specific-img-element-of-a-div-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not give your images classes in alphabetical order. So you have the container with id 1 with images of class a, b, c, etc. Your next container with id 2 and classes a, b, c, d, etc. Then you can access any image easily:

```
#1 .a {
    //css code
}
#2 .d{
    //css code
}
```

etc.

EDIT:

You can add more than one class to the class attribute, i.e.

```
<section id="1">
    <img class="photo 1" id="1"/>
    <img class="photo 2" id="2"/>
    <img class="photo 3" id="3"/>
</section>
```

and apply CSS like so:

```
#1 .1 {
    //css code
}
#2 .2{
    //css code
}
```

Lloan Alas is right that you can only assign unique values to ids, though, so you'll have to ditch the id attribute on your images!

Comment: the class photo is a name that i use in the css to make a slider

Answer (score 1):

You cannot repeat IDs. ID's are meant to be unique.

You can target those images a few different ways, but using `nth-child` is the way I'd go instead of cluttering your CSS with several different IDs.

For example:

```
section#1 > img:first-child { /* first image*/ }
section#1 > img:nth-child(2) { /* second child */ }
section#1 > img:last-child {/* last image */}
```

That should give you an idea of how to target those images.